# Is there a programmatic API for Tibco Business Works

Tags: devops, tibco

Is there a way to configure Tibco Business Works directly from a programming language? That is: can you deploy, configure, test and teardown your APIs from Chef/Puppet/Ansible and are there recipes/playbooks, etc. to do so?

Thank you very much in advance.

Tim

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to automate BW deployments - there are command-line tools (buildear, appManage, ...). You can invoke them from shell scripts (unix, windows, ...) as well as any other programming language that allows to invoke external applications. I use them large-scale via shell scripts in my groups projects.

Most processing instructions are based on command line parameters and the static configs (environment, aliases, instance configs) are based on particular files in the file system tree (which you can also auto-archive, backup, etc.).

The deployment process as such is distributed and based on Tibco Administrator (to which appManage interfaces) so you only have to control the action parameters (via command-line parameters). Your programming language should support that (or do you want to have the command-line tools as java classes to build a single java admin app?).

Comment: Hi Stefan, based on your recent activity you seem to be employed by or associated with Tibco. You might want to edit your profile and add your affiliations to comply with the community standards. See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/how-can-i-use-stack-overflow-to-support-our-developer-community) for details.

Comment: I do work as a consultant for Tibco BW projects but I can't see how the link would help doing things differently. What particularly do you suggest?